# Python: Is this array element replacement correct?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wanted to change all the negative values of an array to be 0. Will the following expression do what I expect?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([3, -3], [5, 2], [1, -5])
x[x < 0] = 0
```

I know this could be done manually, but I want to know that because I need it for a larger personal project.

Comment: And why don't you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes it will, if you provide a valid array. However, the array you are trying to construct is not valid, as `np.array` does not accept multiple array-like parameters. Maybe you meant to write this instead?

`x = np.array([[3, -3], [5, 2], [1, -5]])`

Note the extra pair of brackets surrounding your arguments to create a 2D array.

As others pointed out though, please don't ask simple questions like this on StackOverflow which can easily be confirmed with less than a minute of your own trial and error in a Python shell. The intent is generally to ask about *specific* problems you run into, and to show your attempts at a solution, so you can then be guided into accomplishing what you want.